# How "ip route add" if mask not CIDR

Tags: shell-script, ip, route

How add to route, for example  IP Range `192.168.0.0` and mask `255.255.255.0`

I know that: `255.255.255.0 = 24 (cidr)`, but i need make command in sh script, like:

`route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev ppp0`
but exactly with `ip route` ?

Repeat: , i get 255.255.255.0 as variable in script. , i know about `ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev ppp0`

Any variants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the netmask in both way, just split by a slash:

`ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 dev ppp0`

`ip route add 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0 ppp0`